# 'enhanced' flash satay with conditional ie statements, necessary?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, embed, conditional-statements

we use the flash satay method to embed flash widgets.

we have tested this in countless browsers, older and more modern ones, and they always load the flash widgets.

i have seen 'enhanced' versions of the flash satay method that include a conditional internet explorer statement that include the classid (and codebase) paramater in the object tag.

is this necessary?

as mentioned, we have tested ie6-9, chrome, firefox, opera, etc without this classid'ed version and it seams to load fine.

should we start using the 'enhanced' flash satay method that has this internet explorer only block of code?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think i've ever seen it in a param element but i've seen it on nested objects. same thing i guess. 
classid attribute is IE specific, Gecko ignores it; classid acts as unique identifier, which ActiveX control requires to select which player to use for the media.
basically its a standards-based, valid markup block for your flash with alot of graceful degredation built in.

totally keep it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using the 'Satay' method. Some developers generally got fed up with all the different embed methods and ended up making [SWFObject](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html); a few years pass and now it is considered the standard method of embedding. The goal of SWFObject is to normalize all the quirks of different embedding methods in different browsers so you don't have to worry about them! How nice is that?

Here's an Adobe Dev Net tutorial on using SWFObject to embed your .swf's:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html